# If $\sin(x+28^\circ)=\cos(3x-78^\circ)$, then find x

Tags: trigonometry

$$\sin(x+28^\circ)=\sin (90^\circ-3x+78^\circ)$$
$$x+28^\circ=168^\circ-3x$$
$$x=35^\circ$$
Pretty straightforward question, but then answer is $35^\circ$ **and** $8^\circ$. How is $8^\circ$ the answer?

Comment: $\sin\theta=\sin\phi$, then $\theta=\phi+360^\circ k$ or $\theta= 180^\circ-\phi+360^\circ k$ for integer $k$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that $\;\cos x=\cos\alpha\implies x=\pm\alpha\;$ , so in your case:

$$\sin(x+28)=\cos(90-x-28)=\cos(3x-78)\implies62-x=\pm(3x-78)\implies$$

$$\implies\begin{cases}62-x=3x-78\implies 4x=140\implies x=35\\{}\\or\\{}\\62-x=-3x+78\implies 2x=16\implies x=8\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use $$\sin(x)-\cos(y)=-2 \sin \left(-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{2}+\frac{\pi
   }{4}\right) \sin
   \left(-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{2}+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)$$